# Rails - update variable attribute with dropdown and without save button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table which shows some Leads that are linked to the current user. In this table I have a field "status" which I would like to have as a dropdown. When you select another status in this dropdown, it immediately saves that status for that lead without having to click a "save"-button.

Can someone help/guide me on implementing this?

Thanks in advance,
T

UPDATE: I'm using this script at the moment, though it can't seem to recognize the @lead.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col">Id</th>
      <th class="col">Fullname</th>
      <th class="col">Email</th>
      <th class="col">Phone</th>
      <th class="col">Status</th>
      <th class="col">Created</th>
      <th class="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @leads.each do |lead| %>
    <tr class="<%=cycle('odd', 'even') %> location_row" id="lead_row" data-id="<%= lead.id%>">
      <td><%= lead.id %></td>
      <td><%= lead.fullname %></td>
      <td><%= lead.email %></td>
      <td><%= lead.phone %></td>
      <td><%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Lead.statuses.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}), :id => "lead_status" %></td>
      <td><%= link_to (fa_icon "pencil-square-o "), edit_lead_path({:id => lead.id, :first_last_name => lead.first_last_name}), :title => 'Edit Lead', :class => "action-button" %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#lead_status').on('change', saveStatus);
    function saveStatus() {
      var newStatus = $(this).val();
      var currentStatus = <%= @lead.status %> // replace @lead with your object of Lead class.
      var leadId = <%= @lead.id %>
      if (!(newStatus == "" && newStatus == currentStatus)) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<%= update_lead_status_path({:id => @lead.id}) %>"
          data: {status: newStatus, lead_id: leadId},
          success: function(data) {
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you can do this with `jquery`. you can call  `onchange` method when you select the different status and user Ajax hit to store that value in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col">Id</th>
      <th class="col">Fullname</th>
      <th class="col">Email</th>
      <th class="col">Phone</th>
      <th class="col">Status</th>
      <th class="col">Created</th>
      <th class="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @leads.each do |lead| %>
    <tr class="<%=cycle('odd', 'even') %> location_row" id="lead_row" data-id="<%= lead.id%>" data-status="<%= lead.status %>">
      <td><%= lead.id %></td>
      <td><%= lead.fullname %></td>
      <td><%= lead.email %></td>
      <td><%= lead.phone %></td>
      <td><%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Lead.statuses.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}), :class => "lead_status" %></td>
      <td><%= link_to (fa_icon "pencil-square-o "), edit_lead_path({:id => lead.id, :first_last_name => lead.first_last_name}), :title => 'Edit Lead', :class => "action-button" %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.lead_status').on('change', saveStatus);
    function saveStatus() {
      var newStatus = $(this).val();
      var table_row = $(this).closest('tr');
      var currentStatus = table_row.attr('data-status');
      var leadId = table_row.attr('data-id');
      if (!(newStatus == "" && newStatus == currentStatus)) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<%= update_lead_status_path({:id => @lead.id}) %>"
          data: {status: newStatus, lead_id: leadId},
          success: function(data) {
            table_row.attr('data-status', newStatus);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, do I need to wrap the dropdown with a form? My status field consists of an "enum" so I'm not sure how to list my values without a form..

Comment: No, you don't need a form you can do like this: <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Lead.statuses.map {|k, v| [k.humanize, k]}) %>

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with the view and script that I'm using after your answer + comments. I feel that I'm almost there but at this moment it doesn't recognize the @lead as it regards a table with another lead in every row. Any tips on how to pass the lead id of the row to the script?

Comment: @ThomasC I have made changes as per your updated question. Try this solution.